# A question about considering the solution of elliptic PDE with complex Laplacian as the critical point of a functional

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

I'm considering the elliptic PDE with complex Laplacian, for example, write $$
\Delta_c(\cdot):=-g^{i \bar{j}} \partial_i \partial_{\bar{j}}(\cdot),
$$
and $$\Delta_c(u)=f,$$
by [P.Gauduchon, Math.Ann, 1984], we know that
$$
\Delta_c u=\Delta_{d} u+(d u, \theta)_g,
$$
where is the Hodge-Laplacian plus a gradient term, so I wondered, can we consider the solution as the critical point of a functional, then I recall this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270110/a-problem-from-evans-pdes-book-find-a-lagrangian-for-a-given-euler-lagrange-eq/270774#270774), which said that the energy functional of $$
-\Delta u+D \varphi \cdot D u=f
$$
is $$
I[w]:=\int_U L(D w, w, x) d x
$$ with $L(p, z, x)=e^{-\varphi(x)}\left(\frac{1}{2}|p|^2-f(x) z\right)$.

**But I was told that I can't do this to the complex laplacian, because the representation $$
\Delta_c u=\Delta_d u+(d u, \theta)_g
$$ is 'local', so we could not use variational method, I do not know the reason in detail, could you give me some more explanation if you know the reason?**